# Replacement for Find[:all] in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Fairly Noobish question: I know that activerecord deprecated a bunch from rails 2 to rails 3. I have seen pages like [this](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface), that can explain how complicated strings can be replaced by User.where(etc etc etc.

However, what would be the now functioning solution for a simple replacement? Given a class "User", how would I update User.find[:all] for rails 3 activerecord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find all users you can do it this way

```
User.all # returns Array so you can not chain more Arel methods
```

or scoped method where you have applied your default_scope if you are using it

```
users = User.scoped  # returns ActiveRelation array so you can chain more Arel methods 
users.where(...).order(...)
```

or unscoped method where you skip the default_scope

```
User.unscoped # returns ActiveRelation array so you can chain more Arel methods 
users.where(...).order(...)
```

Comment: One note: `User.all` This will return an array of users, not ActiveRecord collection

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that it might be as simple as that.

Comment: MikhailNikalyukin, what is the difference?